# Stochastic differential equation with Bernoulli random process as a solution

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, absolute-continuity, bernoulli-distribution

Let us assume that $T$ is an absolutely continuous random variable such that $T>0$ almost surely and $\mathbb{E} e^T < \infty$. Let us define

$$ X_t = \mathbb{I}_{ [ t <T ] }, \ t \geq 0 .$$

I would like to write $X$ in the form of a stochastic differential equation, i.e., I want find functions $A$ and $\sigma$ such that

$$ \text{d} X_t = A(t) X_t \text{d} t + \sigma (t) \text{d} W_t . $$

Could somebody give me some advice or a reference to a similar problem.

**Update**

We see that

$$ \mu_t = \mathbb{E} [ X_t ] = \mathbb{P} ( t <T) . $$

If we define $p_t = \mathbb{P} ( t<T)$, then

$$ C(s,t) = \text{cov} (X_s, X_t ) = p_{ t \vee s } ( 1 - p_{s \wedge t } )  .$$

We also want

$$ X_t = \int_{0}^t A(s) X_s \text{d} s + \int_{0}^t \sigma (s) \text{d} W_s .$$

We can compute the expected value function and the covariance function based on the last expression for $X_t$ and then compare it to $\mu_t$ and $C(s,t)$ to infer some properties of $A$ and $\sigma $.

We see that

$$ \mathbb{E} [X_t] = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \int_0^t A(s) X_s \text{d} s \bigg] = \int_0^t A(s) \mathbb{E}_s \text{d}s .$$

Let us treat $p_t$ as a function $p(t)$. Then the last expression gives us

$$ p(t) = \int_0^t A(s) p(s) \text{d}s \Rightarrow p' (t) = A(t) p(t) \Rightarrow A(t) = (\ln p(t))' . $$

We also assume that $T$ is idependent of $W$. Thus, we also see that

$$ \int_0^t A(s) X_s \text{d} s $$

is independent of

$$ \int_0^t \sigma (s) \text{d} W_s .$$

Hence, we get

$$ \mathbb{E} X_t^2 = \int_0^t \sigma^2 (s) \text{d} s + 2p(t) \ln (p(t)), $$

ergo

$$ \sigma^2 (t) = - p' (t) [ 1+ 2 p(t) + \ln (p (t)) ]. $$

Does my approach seem to be correct, or are there any mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process $X_t$ does not admit a representation as an Itô process. To see this, note that $X_t$ does not have continuous paths. However, an Itô process of the form you looked for has continuous paths. In particular, note that

$$\int_0^t A(s) X_s ds$$

is continuous and of bounded variation, and

$$\int_0^t \sigma(s) dW_s$$

is a continuous martingale (and of unbounded variation as soon as $\sigma \not\equiv 0$).